# Change default Java version for agents and script libraries

Tags: java, lotus-notes

As of Notes version 11.0.1, when I create a new Java agent or script library in Designer, it still sets the source compatibility to Java 1.3. This is a pain because I often use features of later Java versions (mainly parameterised types which require Java 1.5), so I nearly always have to manually change the Java version for agents and script libraries.

Is there any way to configure Designer so that the default Java version (and particularly the source compatibility) for new agents and script libraries is at least 1.5, removing the need to manually change it each time?

Workspace settings seem to have no effect on this default, since those are set to 1.8 but new agents and script libraries still use a lower version by default.

I have now submitted a Domino idea on the HCL website, requesting a change to this default on the assumption there's currently no way to change it per-client. https://domino-ideas.hcltechsw.com/ideas/DDXP-I-805

Comment: Struggled with that the other day - and didn't find a solution other than going back to "old" syntax... :-(

Comment: Oh, I suggest reporting it to HCL support. I want to - but just haven't come around that yet....